# JSON parse double quotes

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, double-quotes

I encountered a very strange error. If I run JSON.Parse('[""d""]') then I have error: "Unexpected token d in JSON at position 3"

```js
JSON.parse('["\"d\""]')
```

If I run console.log(JSON.stringify(['"d"'])) then I get '[""d""]'

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(['"d"']))
```

If I run console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(['"d"']))) then I get good result [""d""]

```js
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(['"d"'])))
```

If I use eval function then I have error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 3"

```js
var someJson=JSON.stringify(['"d"']);
window.eval(`JSON.parse('${someJson}')`)
```

How fix it?

I use some external library and there is window.eval(`JSON.parse('${JSON.stringify(t)}'))`). Where t - json array with strings. String can contains double quoutes. It throws exception.

I found js changed my string value when I set it.

```js
var someJson='["\"d\""]';
console.log(someJson);
```

It returns '[""d""]' and when I run JSON.Parse it is incorrect JSON.

How fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> JSON.parse('["\"d\""]')
> ```

`\` is a special character in JS strings, so to include it in your JSON you need to escape it.

```js
const yourString = '["\"d\""]';
const validJSON = '["\\"d\\""]'
const parsedData = JSON.parse(validJSON);

document.querySelector('#yourString').value = yourString;
document.querySelector('#validJSON').value = validJSON;
```

```html
<p>Your string: <output id="yourString"></output>
<p>Valid JSON: <output id="validJSON"></output>
```

As a rule of thumb, embedding JSON in string literals is a waste of time and effort. You can just write the JS data structure you get from parsing the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

@Quentin many thanks for idea! Result answer for me:

```js
var someJson=JSON.stringify(['"d"']);
console.log(window.eval(`JSON.parse('${someJson.replaceAll('\\','\\\\')}')`))
```